# Select all that have the same value in specific column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all the users that share the same value with a particular user.

eg TBL users:

```
id | user | color | value 

 1   Misha  red      30
 2   Kurt   blue    249
 3   Lars   grey     30
 4   Dave   black   249
 5   Steve   orange  30
```

if I want to get users like Lars, I should get: Misha,Steve and Lars. If I want to get users like Kurt, I should get: Dave,Kurt.

I'm posting the actual sql I got it includes a join, i'm having some syntax errors.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(value) FROM users 

WHERE value IN (SELECT value FROM users WHERE user = '{$user}')
INNER JOIN posts  ON users.user  = posts.user
ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit} ";
```

Any help will be thankful.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Try this: 

SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE YT WHERE YT.VALUE IN (SELECT VALUE FROM YOUR_TABLE);

Comment: Just eddited my question, I'm having syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
`user`
FROM your_table
WHERE value IN (SELECT value FROM your_table WHERE `user` = 'Lars');
```

EDIT:

You need to swap lines.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(value) FROM users 
INNER JOIN posts  ON users.user  = posts.user
WHERE value IN (SELECT value FROM users WHERE user = '{$user}')
ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit} ";
```

Comment: Just included your answer in m,y query but i'm having sintax error, must be the join

Comment: You could even change `IN` to `=` here because that subquery will only return one value. That is, unless you can have multiple 'Lars' in your table.

Comment: @MikeSpider Edited my answer to fix your syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this with the help of alias of your table.

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE YT WHERE YT.VALUE IN (SELECT VALUE FROM YOUR_TABLE);
```

Its the DB2 syntax you can look for the IN counterpart in the mysql if it doesn't exist.